# Find and Replace stopped working in android studio 2.1 for windows

Tags: android, android-studio, replace, find

In android studio Find and Replace stopped working, I am not able to find fields, even "Find Usage" is also not working, earlier I have used there features but don't know why suddenly its stopped for me.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio ?

Comment: yes I have tried that